# RichFaces rich:columns and sorting

Tags: jsf, richfaces

does anyone know how to properly enable sorting on a rich:dataTable with columns generated on the fly using rich:columns tag?

Setting sortBy with an expression like #{row[column]} doesn't work for me.

I'm using RichFaces 3.3.1GA.

Here's the example:

```
<rich:dataTable id="table" value="#{localeHandler.locales}" var="row">
    <rich:columns value="#{localeHandler.columns}" var="column" sortBy="#{row[column]}" >
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="#{column}"/>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{row[column]}"/>
    </rich:columns>
</rich:dataTable>
```

whereas the localeHandler.locales is an ArrayList and localeHandler.columns is just an ArrayList containing the following values:

```
language, country, variant, displayName, displayLanguage, displayCountry, displayVariant
```

Comment: what do you mean by doesn't work? it's showing the arrows on the columns, but it doesn't sort when the header is clicked? no arrows? no columns being rendered?

Comment: The arrows are there - they just don't work. I've found out that the last version where this feature worked was 3.3.0.CR1 - since 3.3.0.CR2 it's broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found out that the last version where this feature worked was 3.3.0.CR1 - since 3.3.0.CR2 it's broken.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting sortOrder to a bean property of type org.richfaces.model.Ordering for each column

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at [JIRA RF-6234](http://jira.jboss.org/jira/browse/RF-6234) for workarounds.

Comment: for now we've sticked to version 3.3.0.CR1 for this to work properly but thanks for the update